# Where is ITKConfig.cmake on Fedora?

Tags: cmake, fedora, itk

My program uses

```
FIND_PACKAGE(ITK REQUIRED)
```

it gives me the error message

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ITK" with any of
  the following names:

    ITKConfig.cmake
    itk-config.cmake
```

I've installed the packages itk and itk-devel but none of them has any CMake module. The module from CMake itself is deprecated.

I am using Fedora 23 and CMake 3.4.1

edit:
After downloading ITK 4.9.1 and trying to build it with

```
cmake ../
```

I get the following error:

```
Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wformat=2
Performing Test C_HAS_WARNING-Wformat=2 - Success
Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wformat=2
Performing Test CXX_HAS_WARNING-Wformat=2 - Success
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:243 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/.../InsightToolkit/InsightToolkit-4.9.1/Utilities/KWStyle/KWStyle.cmake


CMake Error at CMake/ITKModuleEnablement.cmake:43 (message):
  No such module "ITKKWIML" needed by "ITKCommon"
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/ITKModuleEnablement.cmake:59 (itk_module_check)
  CMake/ITKModuleEnablement.cmake:59 (itk_module_check)
  CMake/ITKModuleEnablement.cmake:66 (itk_module_check)
  CMakeLists.txt:345 (include)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build and install ITK from source. There is a detailed explanation [here](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Configuring_and_Building).

Once you have finished installing ITK, CMake will be able to find it.

Comment: thx could you take a look into the current problem? It does not find "Utilities/KWStyle/KWStyle.cmake" although the option ITK_USE_KWSTYLE is not set.

Comment: itk and itk-devel packages have nothing to do with "Insight Segmentation and Registration Toolkit". They are used to install [this](http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/extras/6/x86_64/repoview/itk-devel.html). If you want to use ITK, you need to build it from source.

Comment: yes I got that. I was building ITK from the the source (InsightToolkit) but got the missing file error above. But with another version it worked so thx.